# exporting data from a text in a database

Tags: python, postgresql

If I want to save this text file into a database by postgreSQL using python with name, email, phone number, chat starting and end time in different column what I need to do?

```
[11:23] max : Name : max

Email : max@gmail.com

Phone : 01716345678

[11:24] harvey : hello there how can i help you
[11:24] max : can you tell me about the latest feature
```

Comment: can you share what you tried?

Comment: you need to parse text file to extract required data and make an INSERT query to postgres. Your question is pretty broad so it's better to divide it into simple tasks and search on how to do those.